# How to show directions on a map when using the Geolocation Field module

Tags: location, google-maps

I installed the [Get Directions](http://drupal.org/project/getdirections) and the [Geolocation Field](http://drupal.org/project/geolocation) modules.

The Geolocation Field module displays a map, but I also want directions.

How do I get the directions shown on a map? Do I need another module?

Answer (score 1):

When you download the [Get Directions](https://www.drupal.org/project/getdirections) module, it has a `README.txt` that explains how to set up the module.  Make sure to:

Make sure both modules are enabled, then configure the Get Directions module at: **`Administer > Site configuration > Get directions`**.

Go to **`Administer > User management > Permissions`** and set up permissions according to your needs.

Configure up a Geolocation field on a content type, then create a node of that type and fill in the field.  You should then be able to use this URL pattern to see Get Directions module work with that node by going to

> http://{hostname}/getdirections/location/to/{node_id}

or

> http://{hostname}/getdirections/location/from/{node_id}

where {hostname} and {node_id} are filled in with correct values.

Here is the full section on all the options from the README.txt:

> For instance, if you want to "preload" the getdirections form with information
>   about the destination use a URL in this format:
>
> getdirections/location/to/99
>
> Where '99' is the node id (nid) of the location. The user will only
>   have to fill in the starting point.
>
> To do it the other way around use getdirections/location/from/99
>
> You can also get a map with waypoints
>   getdirections/locations_via/1,2,3,99
>
> If you have both the starting point and destination node ids then you
>   can use getdirections/locations/1/99
>
> Where '1' is the starting point node id and 99 is the destination node
>   id (note the 's' in locations)